# JointJS - Using router on links behaves weird

Tags: javascript, svg, jointjs

As long as I don't use any routers or the attribute smooth on my links, everything is drawn correctly. [image: Normal behavior without router]

Now I wanted to use the manhattan router and things started to get weird. Every link is drawn as a filled element instead of a simple line.

It seems to me that something else does modifications on the links which somehow interferes.
[image: Activated manhattan router]

**Furthermore** attributes like link.attr({'.marker-source': { fill: 'red', d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z' }}) are completely ignored. The black arrow heads are still shown.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're missing joint.css, please accept @Roman's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JointJS library core files are `joint.js` and `joint.css`. Please make sure that none of them is missing.

*JointJS + dependencies (jQuery, lodash, backbone)*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="joint.css" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="joint.js"></script>
```

Comment: BINGO! I was missing the CSS file. Now it all works beaftifully. Thank-you

Answer (score 1):

I had to add `fill:none` to both `.connection-wrap` and `.connection` to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `joint.js` library in `react.js` application and I encountered the same issue.
Indeed the problem was with the missing styles.

In my `package.json` the `joint.js` library is declared just like that:
`"jointjs": "^2.2.1",`
In order to add styles, I had to add the following line to import styles: `import "../../node_modules/jointjs/css/layout.css";`

Answer (score 0):

I have added `display: none;` to `.link-tools` and it worked for me.